# bitbucket path naming convention

Tags: bitbucket

I have a bitbucket project where the url is like this:

```
git clone https://myname@bitbucket.org/projectname/backend.git
```

but then another one has this path:

```
git clone https://myname@bitbucket.org/teamname/backend.git
```

and I don't understand why the folder is the team name in one case, but it is the project name in the other case.

Comment: Are these URLs for the same project? If not, what's the confusing part?

Comment: they're from different project, but I don't understand how bitbucket is building these names since they use 2 different systems without any obvious reason.

Comment: How are you differentiating a "project name" and a "team name"? What's to stop me from creating a Bitbucket user or team named after a project?

Comment: nothing prevents your from this, but BitBucket has that Team->Project(s)->Repo(s) hierarchy and each step has a name; A Team can own several projects and each project can own several repos

Comment: Unless you can share the actual URLs with us this is going to be very hard to answer.

Comment: They're not public projects, so you wouldn't be able to navigate the hierarchy in them; when I look at it, it seems like everything created in the last year is bitbucket.org/teamname/... and the older ones bitbucket.org/projectname